# RecyclerView fragment depends on previous fragment with recyclerview

Tags: android

I would like to create shopping list app with 2 fragments.
First fragment contains names of my shopping list, which I create with livedata like:
Market List
Grocery List
Car List
etc.
Then when I click on Market List it goes to second fragment and it shows me another recyclerview where I can add items, products like milk, bread.

I have done almost the whole application two fragments with dialog, add, delete, room etc.
I also receiveing in Second Fragment the name of the itemName in First Fragment and the position of its in recyclerView while onClick from First Adapter.

Now the question is how to connect the first recyclerview with the second?
I was thinking about making
List<List>

What are your suggestions about this?

[image]

EDIT1:
For now if I click on root view on Shopping LIst 1 to any element it navigates to second fragment and displays List every time the same List .
so...
if I click on Shopping List 1 it goes to second fragment displays List,
if I click on Shopping List 2 it goes to second fragment displays List
It always display the same data when it should displays different.
When I click on Root I use navigation bundle to give two values:
position of my clicked element and itemName = Shopping list 1

My ideas:
Edit2

-> 1 idea
Make somehow:
List<List>
...but no idea how to connect it well

->
Use nestedRecyclerView.
On viewRoot element it navigates to second fragment and display only element I clicked which I can expand. That's all and sounds quite easy.

Comment: You mean is first fragment will listen action from second fragment

Comment: Not exactly, I would rather say secondfragment will listen action from firstMain Fragment, because if I delete shopping list 1 in first fragment list of second fragment has to change as well, the index of it from example.
From 2 to 1 on Room...

Comment: But for now I have indepented first fragment and indepented second fragment and really not sure how to implement it well, no idea for now just suggestions.

Comment: I really to answer your question but what you describe is vague to me.

I am not understanding whether the first and second fragments are currently on the same screen or both on 2 different screens.

Comment: when I click on Shopping List 1 will it pop up another screen or just show the product list of 'Shopping List 1'

Comment: When I click shopping list 1 it goes for second fragment and there another SecondrecyclerviewList is shown.

Comment: check EDIT main post

Comment: one to many relationship that's all but ther eis another problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70269212/how-to-handle-one-to-many-entity-relationship-with-room-and-recyclerviews