# How to handle one to many entity relationship with room and recyclerviews?

Tags: android

I would like to have GroceryCategories(GroceryListItems) to many GroceryItems in there I have almost everything in implementation but I have lost at the end of it.

Entities

```
@Entity(tableName = "grocery_items")
data class GroceryItems (

    @ColumnInfo(name = "itemName")
    var itemName: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "itemQuantity")
    var itemQuantity: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "itemPrice")
    var itemPrice: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "shopOwnerId")
    var shopOwnerId  : Int
    ) {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int? = null

}
```

my categories(first recyclerview)

```
@Entity(tableName = "grocery_items_list")
data class GroceryListItems(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "itemName")
    var itemName: String
    ) {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int? = null
}
```

```
data class ShopWithGroceryItems (
    @Embedded val groceryListItems : GroceryListItems,
            @Relation(
                parentColumn = "id",
                entityColumn = "shopOwnerId"
            )
            val groveceryList: List<GroceryItems>
)
```

in fragmet I log new elements

```
        groceryViewModel.getAllGroceryItems().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            groceryRvAdapter.listGrocery = groceryViewModel.getByIdGroceriesWithProducts(1)
//            groceryRvAdapter.list = it
            Log.d("secondrfragment", "${groceryRvAdapter.listGrocery}")
            groceryRvAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        })
```

```
D/secondrfragment: [ShopWithGroceryItems(groceryListItems=GroceryListItems(itemName=test), groveceryList=[GroceryItems(itemName=test, itemQuantity=1, itemPrice=2, shopOwnerId=1), GroceryItems(itemName=test, itemQuantity=1, itemPrice=2, shopOwnerId=1), GroceryItems(itemName=test, itemQuantity=1, itemPrice=2, shopOwnerId=1), GroceryItems(itemName=te, itemQuantity=1, itemPrice=2, shopOwnerId=1), GroceryItems(itemName=ge, itemQuantity=1, itemPrice=2, shopOwnerId=1)])]
```

but in adapter I have size of the list -> 0 and 1:

```
D/size: Items: 0
D/size: ShopsWithItems: 1
```

myAdapter

```
class GroceryRvAdapter (var listGrocery: List<ShopWithGroceryItems> ,var list: List<GroceryItems>, val groceryItemClickInterface: GroceryItemClickInterface, private val vm: GroceryViewModel) : RecyclerView.Adapter<GroceryRvAdapter.GroceryViewHolder>(){


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: GroceryViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.nameTv.text = (listGrocery.get(1)).groveceryList.get(position).itemName
        holder.quantityTv.text = listGrocery.get(1).groveceryList.get(position).itemQuantity.toString()
        holder.rateTv.text = listGrocery.get(position).groveceryList.get(position).toString()
        val itemTotal : Int = listGrocery.get(1).groveceryList.get(position).itemPrice*listGrocery.get(1).groveceryList.get(position).itemQuantity
        holder.amounTv.text = "$ " + itemTotal.toString()


        holder.deleteTv.setOnClickListener {
//            groceryItemClickInterface.onItemClick(list.get(position))
            vm.delete(list[position])
        }

        }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        Log.d("size", "Items: ${ list.size}")
        Log.d("size", "ShopsWithItems: ${listGrocery.size}")
        return list.size
    }
```

EDIT:
SOLVED

The main solution was to directly make livedata with SQL and the livedata depends on position or id I clicked previously.

```
[...] WHERE id = :id
```

Comment: Can you confirm that you are receiving any data at all from the query?

Comment: This may not be your problem but you should probably rename you id columns to be specific `???_id`  like `grocery_items_id` and `grocery_items_list_id` The `@Relation` and `@Embedded` annotations don't like two columns named the same regardless if they belong to 2 different tables.

Comment: Hello, yes 
My program worked fine I could have two independent recyclerview seen on two different fragments.
Now do you have any  suggestions?

I have written this code with method fun from DAO without Livedata, items were added to database but I was using argument in the method like (val id) and in Query transaction, (... WHERE id = :id)

Please help.

Comment: I have change my code + look at edit