# Bad query One-to-many relationship room

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I have problem with room query. I have Theme data class, that have id as primary key:

```
@Entity(tableName = "themes_table")
data class Theme(
        @PrimaryKey
        var id: String = "",
        var specialityId: String = "",
        var details: String = "",
        var lastUpdated: Long = -1,
        var title: String = ""
)
```

and i have Question data class, that have field themeIds (ArrayList):

```
@Entity(tableName = "questions_table")
data class Question(
        val correctAnswer: String = "",
        @PrimaryKey
    val id: String = "",
        val specialityId: String = "",
        val imageFileName: String = "",
        val imageLastUpdated: String = "",
        val lastUpdated: Long = -1,
        var isFavourite: Boolean = false,
        var isExamined: Boolean = false,
        var isLearned: Boolean = false,
        var isCorrect: Boolean = false,
        var isMistake: Boolean = false,
        var selectedAnswer: String = "",
    val order: Int = -1,
        val text: String = "",
        @TypeConverters(ArrayListConverter::class)
    val themeIds: ArrayList<String> = arrayListOf(),
        @TypeConverters(MapConverter::class)
    var variants: MutableMap<String, String> = mutableMapOf()
): Serializable
```

I want to get list of themes with questions like this:

```
data class ThemeWithQuestions(
        @Embedded
        var theme: Theme,
        @Relation(parentColumn = "id", entityColumn = "themeIds", entity = Question::class)
        var questionsList: MutableList<Question> = mutableListOf()
)

@Transaction()
@Query("SELECT * FROM themes_table")
fun getThemesWithQuestions(): MutableList<ThemeWithQuestions>
```

But this query get only themes, questionsList always is empty. Can problem be in this query ? Should i put "IN" statement to it ? How i can resolve it ?

Comment: What you are essentially doing goes against Relational sql paradigm and is easily doable in nosql dbs. The correct approach would be to remove themeIds from Question and than make a table containing themeId and questionId only as a compounded primary key and make queries based on that.

Comment: @RahulRawat , sorry but i don't know how to do this) Can you help me please ?

Comment: What's the use of variants map inside Question?

Answer (score 0):

Try query:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM themes_table WHERE id = :id")
fun getThemesWithQuestions(id: Int): MutableList<ThemeWithQuestions>
```

As well check this maybe it will be helpful

[How to handle one to many entity relationship with room and recyclerviews?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70269212/how-to-handle-one-to-many-entity-relationship-with-room-and-recyclerviews)

Comment: Thx, but i need to get an array of ThemeWithQuestion

Comment: Can you update post with AddQuestion method and query for this?